# How to insert date and time into database when a user logins and logouts in symfony?

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3 to do a project. So I created a login page for the user. When he logs in he gets redirected to the profile page. In the profile page there is a logout button for the user to logout. What I'm trying to do is that when the user logins and logouts, the subsequent date and time should go into the database automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save login Date and Time by listening to the `security.interactive_login` event. Here is how you should do it.

Create a Service for the same :

```
app.authentication_success_handler:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@router']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

Please note : You are passing `entity_manager` in arguments since you will need it to update database.

Next create a class in order to call the service :

```
class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var type
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @var type
     */
    private $router;


    public function __construct(EntityManager $em = null, Router $router)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken();
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $this->onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $path = "_security.main.target_path";
        $session = $request->getSession();

        $referrer = $this->router->generate('homepage'); // default redirect path.

        // Handle gated content, if user has accessed before login,
        if ($session->get($path)) {
            $referrer = $session->get($path);
        }
        $user = $token->getUser();

        //  ############## Do database update here. Since you have access to User Object($user) and Entity manager($this->em).
        $dateTime = new \DateTime();
        $user->setLoginTime($dateTime);
        $this->em->flush();

        return new RedirectResponse($referrer);
    }
}
```

This should work for Saving login time.

**Handling Logout Time :**

You can do so, by implementing a `LogoutHandlerInterface` and adding the handler to your security config.

Create a service :

```
app.logout_handler:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\LogoutListener
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@router']
```

Now, make sure this service is being called when user logs out.

```
// security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            logout:
                handlers: [app.logout_handler]
```

Now you can create another class `AppBundle\EventListener\LogoutListener` 
 which should implement `LogoutHandlerInterface` and save the user information like we did for `app.authentication_success_handler`.

I haven't tested it though. But it should work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you share the controller method for logout in the answer? So that it will become the full answer to the question and I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Hi, It seems there is a way around to save logout time through an handler. I have edited my answer for the same. Please check once.

Comment: Thanks Brodie... :)